# Port Redirecting stop Jersey Webservice

Tags: java, web-services, jersey

I'm using Jersey to publish the following webservice:

```
@Path("/")
public class PagSeguroWS {  

    @Path("/pagseguro_notifications")
    @POST
    public void notification(@FormParam("notificationCode") String notificationCode){
        System.out.println(notificationCode);
        System.out.println("ola");
    }

}
```

I'm testing this using this website: http://requestmaker.com/ because i need simulate POST PARAMS.

So, when i use the link "http://myip:8080/system/ws/pagseguro_notifications" with notificationCode POST PARAM everything works fine.

But i need acess this link (ws/pagseguro_notifications) from PORT 80 (unhappy this is mandatory for consumer and i can't change it), then i created a **port forwarding in my router from 80 to 8080**.

When i access my website with "http://myip/system/somepage" everything works and i can use it normally because port forwarding is working as i hope. 
But when i call the jersey webservice with: "http://myip/system/ws/pagseguro_notifications"  in requestmaker.com the method notification()" is not called.

See the picture in requestMaker.com:

[image]

Comment: Can you post the details you are putting in request maker and the output in the question (i.e. an image preferably)?

Comment: @ColinMc, i edited the post with picture. Sorry for delay.

Comment: The only thing wrong in that image is the Content-Type. The value should be x-www-form-urlencoded. Can you make that change and see if you get a 204 response code back.

Comment: i tried and nothing happens. THe page loading forever

Comment: Try another tool to make a HTTP request then as it seems like a tooling issue.